# symfony doctrine pagination brings more data than set per page

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I am setting 1 row per page in symfony pager but its showing more data than 1. It is because my query is left joining the sfGuardUser table with other tables and it is causing duplication of 'sfGuardUser' row in some cases when there are multiple entries in 'license' table for that particular user ! Here is my query:

```
    $pager = new sfDoctrinePager('sfGuardUser', '1');

     $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
                        ->select('u.id, u.username, g.name, l.id, l.status,             l.client_id, l.vendor_id, l.applied_date, p.org_name')
                        ->from('sfGuardUser u')
                        ->leftJoin('u.Profile p')
                        ->leftJoin('u.Groups g')
                        ->leftJoin('u.LicensedClients l')
                        ->where('g.name = \'vendor\'')
                        ->orderBy('l.applied_date');

     $q->setHydrationMode(Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_SCALAR);

     $pager->setQuery($q);
     $pager->setPage($request->getParameter('page', 1));
     $pager->init();
```

The pagination is there, but problem is in some cases there are multiple rows shown in one page when there are multiple rows for a particular user in the license table. How can I implement it in a right way ?

Answer (score -1):

What do you want to achieve with joining user and license table (1:n relation) when paging through (sfGuard)Users ?

If you want to sort users by license type/date/count, you could use

```
DISTINCT u.id, u.username
```

Comment: DISTINCT doesn't work in doctrine 1.2. better to use GROUP BY.

Comment: @domi27: GROUP BY in this case will not do. I want to paginate the data set returned from the query. In this case say there are 3 users (a,b,c) and user a has 3 different licenses and others have none. The joining will generate 3 row for user 'a' with corresponding license info and 2 more row for user 'b' and 'c' with null value in license related columns. I want to paginate this result set. Currently it paginates such that it shows all user 'a' related data at once then paginates through other one by one..